# Blender keeps Crashing on Macbook M3 Pro

Tags: rendering

I have tried my best and Blender keeps crashing anytime I'm rendering on my MacBook M3 Pro. I have attached the screenshot of the crash error[image]. I am a beginner and I am confused.

This is short description of the error:

`------------------------------------- Translated Report (Full Report Below) ------------------------------------- Process: Blender [4957] Path: /Applications/Blender.app/Contents/MacOS/Blender Identifier: org.blenderfoundation.blender Version: 4.1.0 (4.1.0 2024-03-26) Code Type: ARM-64 (Native) Parent Process: launchd [1] User ID: 501`

Comment: Sorry but crash reports are specifically off-topic here. Ther are no Blender developers here nor does anyone here work for or have any associaltion with the Blender Foundation. Suggest you read [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1377/best-place-to-put-bug-reports) and report it via Blender's Help > Report a bug menu.